# What should a Java program listen for, to be a good Linux service?

Tags: java, linux, service, daemon

In Linux you can give the following commands:

```
service <someService> start
service <someService> stop
```

As opposed to killing the process with `kill -9 <someService>`.  As I learned in an earlier question, this is the difference between sending the process a `SIGTERM` (former) and a `SIGKILL` (latter).

So how does one go about "registering" (and coding) an ordinary JAR or WAR as a service/daemon that can be started and stopped with those commands? I would imagine that Java must have some API for handling `SIGTERM`s?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see this question has already received a closevote for being off topic. I would like to know why! This question is not a *superuser*-type question, it is related to how to program a Java app so that it handles `SIGTERM`s. I suspect the closevoter did not actually read my question.

Comment: Which flavor of Linux? Not all are the same. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/restart-services-service-command-not-found-88809/

Comment: CentOS - but that should only matter if the configuration has to be done at the shell level. If its a Java implementation then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @SpencerKormos regardless of what happens at the operating system level, you need to have your Java code be responsive to the operating system telling you to stop.

Comment: @Thor The question is for starting and stopping, so you need to somehow associate the service name with the Java package, don't you?

Comment: @SpencerKormos that is not what is being asked.  He wants to know what to do in his Java code to be able to shut down properly when requested to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191215/how-to-stop-java-process-gracefully

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you just want to run some shutdown specific code, the "proper Java" way to handle this would not use signals, but would instead add a generic "shutdown hook" that would run when your application was about to terminate.  This is one of those least-common-denominator problems that Java sometimes suffers from.  (Since not all platforms support `SIGINT`, in Java, no platform supports `SIGINT`.)

Unfortunately, you don't get much context in a [`ShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), but it may still be useful:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        // cleanup
    }
}));
```

If you really need to distinguish between the signal received, or you want to support signals that Java normally ignores (like `USR1`), or you want to abort shutdown based on a signal, then a `ShutdownHook` will be mostly useless for you, unfortunately.

There is a non-supported, poorly-documented way to capture signals in the Sun JVM, using the `sun.misc.SignalHandler` class.  This is questionably portable, though it appears that the [IBM JVM also supports this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/i-signalhandling/).

For example - you could hook up a signal handler to listen to `SIGHUP` reload your server configuration, which was set up in the `init.d` script as the `reload` verb:

```
Signal.handle(new Signal("HUP"), new SignalHandler() {
    public void handle(Signal signal)
    {
        reloadConfiguration();
    }
});
```

As for configuring a Java application to be controlled using the `system` command, you should write a shell script in `init.d` program that starts it up.  This simply needs to respond to the `start` and `stop` verbs and take the appopriate action.  For example, this could be your `/etc/init.d/my-java-program`:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
start)
    java /path/to/my/java/program.jar &
    echo $! > /var/run/my-java-program.pid
    ;;

stop)
    if [ ! -f /var/run/my-java-program.pid ]; then
        echo "my-java-program: not running"
        exit 1
    fi

    kill -TERM `cat /var/run/my-java-program.pid`
    ;;

reload)
    if [ ! -f /var/run/my-java-program.pid ]; then
        echo "my-java-program: not running"
        exit 1
    fi

    kill -HUP `cat /var/run/my-java-program.pid`
    ;;

*)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/my-java-program {start|stop|reload}"
    exit 1
    ;;

esac

exit 0
```

You can now start your application by running `/etc/init.d/my-java-program start`, or on CentOS, you can also use service my-java-program start`.

Comment: Thanks Edward - so does that mean I can run `service <someService> {start|stop}` on any of my Java processes? I ask because this is how one starts/stops Tomcat politely, and I'd like my Java app to behave the same.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with the CentOS `service` mechanism.  But on Debian and Ubuntu, I use the `/etc/init.d/myProgram start` and `stop` mechanisms without any problem.

Comment: Thanks again - I'm really not trying to be difficult here, I'm just having a tough time understanding the connection between how a shell-level call (either `service <service> start` or `start <service>` in your case) maps to Java being kickstarted and fed the application as an argument. I think once I understand that relation I'll be all set. Thanks again for such amazing help!

Comment: ShutdownHook does not in any way respond to external stimuli.  It is just a facility to be able to run code at exit time.

Comment: @AdamTannon The Tomcat stop scripts invoke Java code which talks to the Tomcat JVM through a network and tell it to stop.  You typically do not have that luxury for ordinary non-network applications.

Comment: *sigh* Why doesn't anyone but me and the OP understand the first part of his question? He's asking how to configure init.d to start his shell script, a la this StOf entry here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6237997/8528.

Comment: So here it is with a little Googling: http://support.suso.com/supki/CentOS_Init_startup_scripts  You need to write a shell script which either calls "java" with your class/jar info, or wraps a shell script that you wrote to start your app, and can accept the start/stop/restart options. "start" launches your app as a process, "stop" kills the process, and the ShutdownHook lets you clean up when the process is terminating.

Comment: @SpencerKormos: I updated to add an example `init.d` to start/stop.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, by "...using the `system` command...", did you mean "...using the `service` command..." ?

Comment: It's rather odd that Java, which is so often used to write processes on servers, does not provide a way to respond to the standard unix signals for managing processes on servers. If you want signal-based handling, seems like the easiest workaround is to wrap the java invocation in a shell script, and then have that script communicate with the jvm app instance via a pipe or some other means. Not easy.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot define signal handlers for different signals in pure Java, like you would in a native Unix program. This means that you can't follow common conventions of e.g. having the program reload its configuration on `SIGHUP` and do a clean shutdown on `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`.

What you can do is define a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29). They are run when the virtual machine is going to shut down, e.g. after receiving `SIGTERM`. Here's an example:

```
Runnable myShutdownHook = new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        System.out.println("I'm melting! What a world...");
    }
};

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(myShutdownHook));
```